Creating spaces from a Spring Boot API with Spring Data Elasticsearch (ElasticsearchRepository)
I need to build a Spring Boot API that interacts with an Elasticsearch database for creating spaces
I just wanna know if its possible to execute the following request from this API using the Spring Data Elasticsearch:
POST /api/spaces/space
https://www.elastic.co/docs/api/doc/kibana/operation/operation-post-spaces-space
If there is not way to create a space using Spring Data, is there any other options for the repository layer in this Spring Boot API that I can create those spaces?
Thank you so much in advance.

For making a POST-request, maybe you should consider using org.springframework.web.client.RestClient or
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.
